# Python bank game won't go back up

Tags: python

Python
i am making a python online imaginary bank.
You can either pay or take out.
when account = $0, then your account closes and the program ignores any further action from the user. You can still keep paying and withdrawing because you won't know but account is closed. when you quit program it will display that account is closed. so how do i make it so that once account = $0, the money won't go up when a user deposits money?

p.s. I don' have a code because I have just started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while loop that checks whether the value of account is zero would be a way to quit:

```
while account != 0:
```

Floating point zero is not always precisely zero:

```
>>> 27.33 - 25.0 - 2.33
-1.7763568394002505e-15
```

If account is a float variable, you have to make allowances for this:

```
while abs(account) < 0.000000001:
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I just realized! :-)

Comment: I would recommend `while account <= 0:`, because if you have `$100` and you want to take out `$200`, it skips directly over the value of `$0`.